# How do use ionic 6 with Auth0 ionic sample and retrieve data saved to cacheLocation: "localstorage",

Tags: ionic-framework, auth0, capacitor

I am using the https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic-samples/tree/main/angular and following the examples in the readme file to to letter

Allowed Callback URLs:
`com.auth0.samples://XXXX/capacitor/com.auth0.samples/callback, capacitor://localhost, http://localhost, http://localhost:4200`

Allowed Logout URLs:
`com.auth0.samples://XXXXX/capacitor/com.auth0.samples/callback, http://localhost:4200`

Allowed Origins (CORS):
`capacitor://localhost, http://localhost`

Allowed Web Origins:
`http://localhost:4200`

And it worked twice and then all further testing I received this error

> Failed to launch 'com.auth0.samples://dev-zhh5r4vf5zhgl2w4.us.auth0.com/capacitor/com.auth0.samples/callback?code=XXXXX&state=OGhsemEyWmF3MXlrOHkyVjRsanRhOVVKZ1dNZjdSb0swMlc3OWUtVnZYOA%3D%3D' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Using
ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
   user$ = this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(switchMap(() =>    this.auth.user$));
   constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
```

html

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user" class="profile-container">
   <ion-avatar class="avatar">
      <img [src]="user.picture" [alt]="user.name" />
   </ion-avatar>
   <h2>name {{ user.name }}</h2>
   <p> email {{ user.email }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting this error on iOS or Android?

Comment: If you're just looking to get something working, you might try OktaDev Schematics. https://github.com/oktadev/schematics#ionic

Comment: Seems to have intermittent login faults.  I will keep testing and post my results and github code

Comment: Is it possible to view the JWT being sent to the App after a successful login

Comment: `... the scheme does not have a registered handler` – that sounds like a problem on the OS level, not relevant to JWT token. As I understand, "scheme" is `com.auth0.samples` and OS can't find a handler for it. It has something to do with the installation/configuration of the app. Try to re-install the sample app.

Comment: The error only happens on web. On a device it now works as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The demo at https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic-samples/tree/main/angular has been updated and now works well on iOS and Android. Please note `ionic serve -p 4200` will work maybe once but will still give the error:

> Failed to launch 'com.auth0.samples://dev-zhh5r4vf5zhgl2w4.us.auth0.com/capacitor/com.auth0.samples/callback?code=XXXXX&state=OGhsemEyWmF3MXlrOHkyVjRsanRhOVVKZ1dNZjdSb0swMlc3OWUtVnZYOA%3D%3D' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.